How can I find UUID for RAID array after reconnecting disks?
I set up a RAID-5 array with my disks plugged into a hub. Then I removed the hub from the setup and plugged my disks directly into the computer.
Having done so, I still see my raid device md0 appear in the output of lsblk, but the mount rule I had saved in in /etc/fstab fails.
How can I mount my RAID device at this point? (I confess that I'm totally new to RAID.)
tail -n 1 /etc/fstab
# => UUID=028562ba-e12d-4574-80c4-a6831c38abcb /mnt/raid5 ext4 rw,relatime,nofail 0 0

sudo lsblk
# => NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
# => sda           8:0    0 10.9T  0 disk  
# => └─sda1        8:1    0 10.9T  0 part  
# =>   └─md0       9:0    0    0B  0 raid5 
# => sdb           8:16   0 10.9T  0 disk  
# => └─sdb1        8:17   0 10.9T  0 part  
# =>   └─md0       9:0    0    0B  0 raid5 
# => mmcblk0     179:0    0 28.8G  0 disk  
# => ├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  512M  0 part  /boot/firmware
# => └─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 28.3G  0 part  /

sudo blkid
# => /dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="bootfs" LABEL="bootfs" UUID="5DF9-E225" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="b7f363ab-01"
# => /dev/mmcblk0p2: LABEL="rootfs" UUID="3b614a3f-4a65-4480-876a-8a998e01ac9b" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b7f363ab-02"
# => /dev/sdb1: UUID="33dd8e6f-579b-425c-e7f8-56613131f80e" UUID_SUB="0a155653-ee2f-9307-c42e-7ad71e35deb7" LABEL="pi-nas:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="b3ca4b97-17c3-410c-9c48-a2a74aac43dc"
# => /dev/sda1: UUID="33dd8e6f-579b-425c-e7f8-56613131f80e" UUID_SUB="7bdb943b-4691-eb94-e522-a23dad403bbb" LABEL="pi-nas:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="b0e25b1e-f164-4434-8697-7911cda014a8"


As you have the same UUID for both partitions /dev/sda1 & /dev/sdb1, I would use in /etc/fstab UUID=33dd8e6f-579b-425c-e7f8-56613131f80e instead of UUID=028562ba-e12d-4574-80c4-a6831c38abcb

What does cat /proc/mdstat show? Will it change if you do a sudo mdadm --assemble --scan?

Thanks, @telcoM. sudo mdadm --assemble --scan did start the repair process, and /proc/mdstat displayed the status. It took about a week and finished yesterday evening.

The fstab entry you're showing is commented out, so it won't work with mount.  Rather than commenting it out you might want to use the noauto option so it doesn't try to automatically mount at boot time but only when you manually request it
e.g.
UUID=028562ba-e12d-4574-80c4-a6831c38abcb /mnt/raid5 ext4 rw,relatime,noauto 0 0

fstab UUIDs are related the filesystem on the block device, and not the block device itself.
Because the UUID is related to the filesystem, it should not change when you removed the hub; so it should be the same as before.
However if you have lost the UUID then you can find it pretty easily.
In  your entry you're showing it's an ext4 filesystem, so you can get the UUID of it using the command dumpe2fs.  You know the disk is /dev/md0
e.g on my machine I have md1 so I can do
 sudo dumpe2fs -h /dev/md1
dumpe2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
Filesystem volume name:   /
Last mounted on:          /
Filesystem UUID:          811e5cfb-8f2f-43fd-bbed-f113829bdece
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
...

(more data excluded).

Ha ha! I didn't mean to indicate that the line in my fstab is really commented; I used # to try to indicate that it was the output of my tail command rather than being a new command in the code block.

Thanks for the tip on noauto. When I try dumpe2fs -h /dev/md0, I get dumpe2fs: Invalid argument while trying to open /dev/md0 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock. Alas. I wonder if my filesystem is wrecked.

either run lsblk with these options, or do this alias for convenience
alias lsblk2='lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,serial,uuid'
use the label option also if you need it, do lsblk --help to see available -o choices.
lsblk output will be similar to
  SIZE FSTYPE   MODEL            NAME   SERIAL                           UUID
  3.5T          PERC H740P Adp   sda    00edc23529854d432d006bbd48f0a7ce
   95M vfat                      ├─sda1                                  BFD0-A8EE
  953M xfs                       ├─sda2                                  dab135ce-9be6-4b3d-a3e1-e19c35e73642
  3.3T xfs                       ├─sda3                                  b75b4987-f101-4f61-8557-8407586b30f0
186.3G xfs                       └─sda4                                  f0f94bfc-342a-41c3-9249-3c3106e893bc
   21T          PERC H740P Adp   sdb    005561c167af4d432d006bbd48f0a7ce
   21T xfs                       └─sdb1                                  d869763a-ab9a-49b4-a834-1366c3cd8393

which then corresponds to df -h output
/dev/sda3            3.4T  173G  3.2T   6% /
/dev/sda2            946M  374M  573M  40% /boot
/dev/sda4            187G  2.3G  184G   2% /home
/dev/sdb1             21T   13T  8.7T  59% /data
/dev/sda1             95M  5.8M   90M   7% /boot/efi

and how you would specify in /etc/fstab
UUID=b75b4987-f101-4f61-8557-8407586b30f0   /                       xfs     defaults                                       0 0
UUID=dab135ce-9be6-4b3d-a3e1-e19c35e73642   /boot                   xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid                          0 0
UUID=BFD0-A8EE                              /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt,nodev,nosuid        0 2
UUID=f0f94bfc-342a-41c3-9249-3c3106e893bc   /home                   xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid,uquota,gquota            0 0
UUID=d869763a-ab9a-49b4-a834-1366c3cd8393   /data                   xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid,nofail                   0 0

my /dev/sdb1 is 6 disks as raid-5 under a dell PERC.
a smartctl --scan will identify all disks behind a raid card, and then you can do smartctl -a -d megaraid,# /dev/sda to access specifically each disk via megaraid number if you so desire to recognize specifically each actual disk.

Alas, using the UUID from /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 in my fstab results in mount: /mnt/raid5: /dev/sdb1 already mounted or mount point busy.. dmesg provides some added detail which confounds me: https://pastebin.com/GgrNsQcX
